# How to use .some() method on an array with 1 object?

Tags: javascript

For example I have this array of object:

```js
const heights = [{tom: 160, jack:180, alex: 186}]
```

How can I use `.some()` method on an object that is inside an array?

Expected:

```js
if (heights.some((el) => el > 185)) {
  console.log('Some of them are taller than 185')
}
//Output: Some of them are taller than 185
```

Comment: Does this array have only one object or more objects with the same key value pattern (name:height)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array really only has one object, extract just that object and take its values to compare:

```js
const heights = [{tom: 160, jack:180, alex: 186}]
if (Object.values(heights[0]).some((el) => el > 185)) {
  console.log('Some of them are taller than 185')
}
```